# solve for a parameter such that area under curve equals 1

Tags: matlab, solver, numerical-integration

I have just found that I can use the function `trapz` in Matlab to find the area under a curve given a vector. What I want to do is to normalize the values in this vector in such that the area under the curve equals `1`. let's say that `x` is a single scaling factor such that:

```
Area_Under_curve(x * V) = 1
```

How can I find x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
x = 1/trapz(V)
```

will do just that :)